# Send HTML email using C# with Amazon SES with Plaintext version included

Tags: c#, html-email, amazon-ses

I can send emails using C# and the Amazon SES API fine. However, I'd like to include a plaintext version alongside each HTML email for various reasons.

I can't find any examples of how to add a plain text version to an HTML email in C# using Amazon SES. Is this possible?

This is the code I'm using to send an HTML email with no plain text version:

```
private string SendEmailHTMLViaAmazonSESAPI(string fromName, string fromEmail, string toEmail, string subject, string body)
{
    try
    {
        if (toEmail.Length > 5)
        {
            using (IAmazonSimpleEmailService client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
            {
                var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
                {
                    Source = fromName + "<" + fromEmail + ">",
                    Destination = new Destination { ToAddresses = new List<string> { toEmail } },
                    Message = new Message
                    {
                        Subject = new Content(subject),
                        Body = new Body { Html = new Content(body) }
                    }
                };

                // Send email using AWS SES
                SendEmailResponse response = client.SendEmail(sendRequest);
                return "Email Sent";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error: Invalid Email";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to stop returning a string and use VOID. Then throw exceptions and catch higher up on error.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html
This link details how to send multi-part emails, (e.g. html + plain text).

In essence, it uses the "multipart/mixed" mime-type, along with "multipart/alternative" to specify the alternative format for the message.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any C# examples, that link doesn't and I can find nothing on Google

Comment: Here: https://neildeadman.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/amazon-simple-email-service-example-in-c-sendrawemail/

Comment: Thanks, although that code example is from 2011, it's probably rather heavily deprecated. Any newer examples out there?